# Can someone explain ja_JP.UTF8?

Tags: character-encoding

I know utf8,but what's the difference between *.utf8?

From [the answer to my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048347/how-to-specify-encoding-while-process-csv-file-in-php/2048358#2048358)

Comment: Between *.utf8 and what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Locale = ja_JP 
Encoding = UTF-8
```

Comment: Where to look up locales for different countries?

Comment: unicode.org's cldr repo, http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-1-7/common/main/

Answer (score 2):

Before Unicode, handling non-english characters was done using tricks like Code Pages (like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305152.aspx)) and special character sets (like this: [Shift_JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS)). UTF-8 contains a much larger range of characters with a completely different mapping system (i.e. the way each character is addressed by number).

When setting `ja_JP.UTF8` as the locale, the "UTF8" part signifies the encoding for the special characters needed. For example, when you output a currency amount in the Japanese locale, you will need the ¥ character. The encoding information defines which character set to use to display the ¥.

I'm assuming there could exist a `ja_JP.Shift_JIS` locale. One difference to the UTF8 one - among others - would be that the ¥ sign is displayed in a way that works in this specific encoding.

**Why ja_JP?**

The two codes `ja_JP` signify **language** (I think based on [**this ISO norm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639)) and **country** (based on [**this one**](http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements)). This is important if a language is spoken in more than one country. In the german speaking area, for example, the Swiss format numbers differently than the germans: `1'000'000` vs. `1.000.000`. The country code serves to define these distinctions within the same language.

Answer (score 1):

In which context? ja_JP tells us that the string is in the Japanese language. That does not have anything to do with the character encoding, but is probably used - depending on context -  for sorting, keyboard input and language on displayed text in the program.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say each utf8 file with that naming convention contains a language definition for translating your site.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [locale](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_19.html) name.  The basic format is language`_`COUNTRY.  `ja` = Japanese language, `JP` = Japan.

In addition to a date format, currency symbol, etc., each locale is associated with a character encoding.  This is a historical legacy from the days when every language had its own encoding.  Now, UTF-8 provides a common encoding for *every* locale.

The reason `.UTF8` is part of the locale *name* is to distinguish it from older locales with a different encoding.  For example, there's an `ja_JP.EUC-JP` locale available on my system.  And for Germany, there's the choice of `de_DE` (obsolete pre-Euro locale with ISO-8859-1 encoding), `de_DE@euro` (ISO-8859-15 encoding, to provide the € sign), and `de_DE.UTF-8`.